# What permissions are required to run Hive Cli

Tags: hive, hdfs, kerberos

I'm seeing an issue with running the Hive CLI. When I run the CLI on an edge node I receive the following error regarding HDFS permissions:

```
c784gnj:~ # sudo hive
/usr/lib/hive/conf/hive-env.sh: line 5: /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-hbase-handler-1.1.0-cdh5.5.2.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-common.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/lib/htrace-core4-4.0.1-incubating.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/lib/htrace-core-3.2.0-incubating.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/lib/htrace-core.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-hadoop2-compat.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-client.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-server.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-hadoop-compat.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-protocol.jar: No such file or directory
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
16/10/11 10:35:49 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.metastore.local does not exist

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.5.2.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=app1_K, access=WRITE, inode="/user":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkFsPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:216)
```

What is hive trying to write to in the /user directory in HDFS?

I can already see that /user/hive is created:

```
drwxrwxr-t   - hive          hive                0 2015-03-16 22:17 /user/hive
```

As you can see I am behind kerberos auth on Hadoop.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log says you need to set permission on HDFS `/user` directory to user `app1_K`

**Command**

`hadoop fs -setfacl -m -R user:app1_K:rwx /user`

Execute this command as privileged user from Hadoop bin

If you get similar permission error on any other hdfs directory, then you have to grant permission on that directory.

Refer the below link for more information.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#ACLs_Access_Control_Lists

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling HDFS access privileges altogether, as suggested by @Kumar, you might simply **create a HDFS home dir** for every new user on the system, so that Hive/Spark/Pig/Sqoop jobs have a valid location to create temp files...

On a Kerberized cluster:

```
kinit hdfs@MY.REALM
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/app1_k
hdfs dfs -chown app1_k:app1_k /user/app1_k
```

Otherwise:

```
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/app1_k
hdfs dfs -chown app1_k:app1_k /user/app1_k
```

Comment: The user already has a home directory, as I am able to use hbase / spark hadoop fs using this user.